# react-navigation accessing navigation state in cardStyleInterpolator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have a Stack Navigator that uses either a modal or slide transition depending on the screen.

i.e. a transition sequence might look like: 
HomeScreen `-Slide>` Screen1 `-Modal From Bottom>` Screen2

This used to not be a problem, but the updated modal transitions cause there to be noticeable "glitches" due to the varying card interpolation styles. I know I can fix this by adjusting the cardStyle interpolation values based on the current/previous screen.

Is there any way to access the `navigation` object for the Stack Navigator when creating the `cardStyleInterpolator`?

EDIT:
`cardStyleInterpolator` (incomplete):

```
export const cardStyleInterpolator = ({
   index,
   current,
   next,
   inverted,
   layouts: { screen },
   insets,
 }) => {
  const isLandscape = screen.width > screen.height;
  const topOffset = isLandscape ? 0 : 10;
  const statusBarHeight = insets.top;
  const aspectRatio = screen.height / screen.width;

  const progress = add(current.progress, next ? next.progress : 0);

  const translateY = multiply(
    progress.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
      outputRange: [
        screen.height,
        index === 0 || index === 1 ? 0 : topOffset,
        (index === 0 || index === 1 ? statusBarHeight : 0) - topOffset * aspectRatio,
      ],
    }),
    inverted
  );

  const overlayOpacity = progress.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1, 1.0001, 2],
    outputRange: [0, 0.3, 1, 1],
  });

  const scale = isLandscape
    ? 1
    : progress.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
      outputRange: [
        1,
        1,
        screen.width ? 1 - (topOffset * 2) / screen.width : 1,
      ],
    });

  const borderRadius = isLandscape
    ? 0
    : index === 0 || index === 1
      ? progress.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
        outputRange: [0, 0, 10],
      })
      : 10;

  return {
    cardStyle: {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      borderTopLeftRadius: borderRadius,
      borderTopRightRadius: borderRadius,
      marginTop: index === 0 || index === 1 ? 0 : statusBarHeight,
      transform: [{ translateY }, { scale }],
    },
    overlayStyle: { opacity: overlayOpacity },
  };
};
```

This `cardStyleInterpolator` is a modified version of the `forModalPresentationIOS`. The modification of adding `index === 1` to the conditionals helps the transition from Screen2 -> Screen1. Since we pushed from HomeScreen to Screen1, when we nav back to Screen1 we want it to animate as if it was the initial route and not another modal.

The current `forModalPresentationIOS` assumes that index 0 is always the index where we use the modal transition from, but when overriding the `cardStyleInterpolator` of index 1 to use the slide transition causes this assumption to be invalid.

Comment: Can you please add the snippet of your `cardStyleInterpolator` ?

Comment: What are the glitches? Also you get access to `navigation` object if you're using `navigationOptions` a s a function where you specify `cardStyleInterpolator`

Comment: Updated with more information. Hope that makes sense and clarifies things.

@satya164 I'm able to get the `navigation` object of the individual screens by settings `defaultNavigationOptions` on the stackConfig, but that doesn't contain a state which shows me the previous route in the overall stack.

Comment: `navigation.dangerouslyGetState()` gives you the state you want

Comment: ahh looks like it's `dangerouslyGetParent`, but that should work. Thanks!